# OpenImageI/O python bindings for color conversion failing

Tags: video

Posted a need to convert color spaces from Linear to AlexaLog ealier, ended up using oiio to do it, but now i get a tone of errors when i try to adapt it for python. Using Terminal it works just fine but python it throws lots of errors at me. The pythonic bindings are here but they seem to not work for me, considering my self a newbie at code was hoping some veterans here can decode this for me as to what im doing wrong

my working code in terminal

```
oiiotool --colorconfig /Users/shaunansari/Desktop/ocio/OCIOConfigs/configs/nuke-default/config.ocio  -i source.exr --iscolorspace linear --tocolorspace AlexaV3LogC  -o shaun.jpg
```

Basically just taking a single EXR and running it through the nuke library and applying the correct colorspace (AlexaV3LogC) to it.

Now as my loop is python based i want to run this in python, user documentation for oiio over at github says to do the following:

```
\subsection{Color manipulation}
\label{sec:iba:py:color}

\apiitem{ImageBuf ImageBufAlgo.{\ce colorconvert} (src, from, to, unpremult=True, \\
  \bigspc\bigspc context_key="", context_value="", \\
  \bigspc\bigspc  colorconfig="", roi=ROI.All, nthreads=0) \\
bool ImageBufAlgo.{\ce colorconvert} (dst, src, from, to, unpremult=True, \\
  \bigspc\bigspc context_key="", context_value="", \\
  \bigspc\bigspc  colorconfig="", roi=ROI.All, nthreads=0)
}
\index{ImageBufAlgo!colorconvert} \indexapi{colorconvert}
Apply a color transform to the pixel values.

\smallskip
\noindent Examples:
\begin{code}
    Src = ImageBuf ("tahoe.jpg")
    Dst = ImageBufAlgo.colorconvert (Src, "sRGB", "linear")
\end{code}
\apiend
```

I tried to go step by step but it just breaks

my python code:

```
    import os
    import OpenImageIO as OIIO
    from OpenImageIO import ImageInput, ImageOutput, ImageBuf, ImageSpec, ImageBufAlgo

    pic = "/Users/shaun/Desktop/img.exr"
    nuke_config = "/Users/shaun/Desktop/ocio/OCIOConfigs/configs/nuke-default/config.ocio"

    Src = ImageBuf (pic)
    Dst = ImageBufAlgo.colorconvert(pic, "Linear", "sRGB", unpremult=True,
        context_key="",context_value="",
        colorconfig="nuke_config", roi=ROI.All, nthreads=0)

Outputs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shaunansari/Desktop/colour.py", line 11, in <module>
    colorconfig="", roi='All', nthreads=0)
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    ImageBufAlgo.colorconvert(str, str, str)
did not match C++ signature:
    colorconvert(OpenImageIO_v1_8::ImageBuf {lvalue} dst, OpenImageIO_v1_8::ImageBuf src, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > from, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > to, bool unpremult=False, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > context_key='', std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > context_value='', std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > colorconfig='', OpenImageIO_v1_8::ROI roi=<OpenImageIO.ROI object at 0x11224a0d8>, int nthreads=0)
    colorconvert(OpenImageIO_v1_8::ImageBuf {lvalue} dst, OpenImageIO_v1_8::ImageBuf src, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > from, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > to, bool unpremult=False, OpenImageIO_v1_8::ROI roi=<OpenImageIO.ROI object at 0x11224a050>, int nthreads=0)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

No clue as to whats missing here lots of variables very little answers i'm getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to color_convert is using a **string** as the "src" parameter instead of the expected **ImageBuf** type.

It should look like this with only the minimum set of params:

```
Src = ImageBuf (pic)
Dst = ImageBufAlgo.colorconvert(Src, "Linear", "sRGB")
```

I suggest your try with minimal params first and add the context and color config afterward...